# How to open chrome developer console using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to open developer console in chrome using selenium webdriver.
I am doing

> from selenium import webdriver
>
> from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains, keys

...

> browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chrm\chromedriver.exe")
>   browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/groups/GNexus5/")

...

> action = action_chains.ActionChains(browser)
>
> action.send_keys(keys.Keys.CONTROL+keys.Keys.SHIFT+'j')
>
> action.perform()

But it is not opening up developer console.
I have tried other keys (just typing some key-strokes, control-selecting some element) and they are working.

I am using ChromeDriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you are in desperate and your OS is Windows, you can simply do this with adding AutoHotKey script to Python code. You can download AutoHK from [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

Install AutoHK. Then you create new script in notepad: just put one short string

`Send ^+J`

and save it as `script.ahk`. These actions will takes 2-3 minutes. Then call it in your code

```
browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/groups/GNexus5/")
import os
os.system("path_to_script.ahk/script.ahk")
```

and this gonna work :)

Comment: I don't mean that. But I've tried `send_keys` as well as key_down and no result in both cases. Also tried in Firefox browser and it works. So it seams that ChromeDriver doesn't support keys combinations and if in not a mandatory for you to use Chrome you can just replace one line in your code with `browser = webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: @Andersson the question is about how to open the Chrome developer console, so using Firefox obviously isn't a viable workaround.

Answer (score 5):

Tell selenium to include a ''auto-open-devtools-for-tabs'' when launching chrome, here is an example using nightwatch configuration:

```
...

chrome: {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    acceptSslCerts: true,
    chromeOptions: {
      'args': ['incognito', 'disable-extensions', 'auto-open-devtools-for-tabs']
    }
  }
},
...
```

Answer (score 4):

With pyautogui you can do the keyboard press and open the console in the tab you have in foucs.

```
    import pyautogui
    pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
    pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
    pyautogui.press('j')
    pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
    pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's not opening the dev-tools pane itself, I would refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67171859/5771107) which explains how to run commands specific to the dev-tools console.

If you really need to open the pane itself, there's probably an answer in the [dev-tools documentation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/).

FYI You need `Selenium version 4.0.0.b3` to do these actions. Dev-tools isn't supported in the stable release.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 4.1.3
Driver Version: ChromeDriver
Python 3 programming language

In order to open the developer toolbar in the browser, you need to add an option with the value options.add_argument("auto-open-devtools-for-tabs"). Such an argument, so you change the initial launch settings of chromedriver and open the browser together with the "Developer Panel" call

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("auto-open-devtools-for-tabs") # <---

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Please add some kind of explanation to your solution

Comment: @vahid-tajari added an explanation

Comment: For some one if you are using "options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)",
You may meet current url is "devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_app.html" when you re-connect to the opened browser, use "driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])" CAN help switch to the correct tab.

Answer (score -3):

`driver.find_element_by_xpath(<any element_name on the webpage>).send_keys(Keys.F12)`

This opens the developer console directly!

You can also use other find_by methods.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I tried `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.F12)` but nothing happens.

Comment: Worked for me using an Xpath locator.