# Access getEventListeners from chrome webdriver (python)

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, selenium

### Aim:

Get all events attached to a node from selenium webdriver

---

I'm using selenium-python and I'd like to execute a javascript script (through `driver.execute_script('my js script')`.

This script uses `getEventListeners` which is only available on **Chrome**.
I used successfully

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver')
```

to launch a chrome browser. Executing my script with `getEventListeners(myNode)` I get something like:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 403, in execute_script
>       {'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: getEventListeners is not defined

`getEventListeners` is available through the Command Line API but I can't make it work from selenium. Is there a solution for this? Is there any other way to get all events binded to an element ? (especially Click event)

Cheers

Comment: I was having the same issue and believe this is a bug. I reported the issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1320

Comment: According to this page https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference as getEventListeners is part of Command Line API, "This API is only available from within the console itself. You cannot access the Command Line API from scripts on the page".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly the answer is: Accessing `getEventListeners` via `ChromeDriver` is not possible. This is -- as mentioned in the comments -- [by design](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities):

> Warning: These functions only work when you call them from the Chrome DevTools Console. They won't work if you try to call them in your scripts.

The according [issue report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1320) was set to `WontFix`.

**BUT:**

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6434924/2484903) for finding all events attached to a node without using `getEventListeners`.

Answer (score 3):

Update for 2021:

There is a beta release of Selenium that offers a Chrome dev-tools API. It's hardly documented but does seem to work for simplistic dev-tools-only JS commands.

e.g.
`pip install -Iv selenium==4.0.0.b3`

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver')
js_return = browser.execute_cdp_cmd(command, options)
```

where the `command` and `options` are defined [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) in the left-hand scroll pane (particularly the `Runtime` section).

Comment: Would that work for the particular problem of getting getEventListeners? Havn't tested it !

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to work. With 4.0.0-rc-2 using the java client I get:
`Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: {"id":1,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"'getEventListeners' wasn't found"}}`

(Also I've no idea how I would pass useful arguments to it with the params map, but that might be solvable?)