# How to access event listeners of element using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm writing a web scraper using `Selenium`/`Python`, and I need to access and call the onclick handler of a specific element using `execute_script`. Seems the event listener is set via `addEventListener()` rather than assign the `onclick` property of the element, so the `onclick` property of the element is `null`.

I can easily access the handler at Chrome Developer Console using the `getEventListeners` function, but since the function is limited to Chrome DevTools Console, I can't use it when I call Selenium `execute_script`([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204449/access-geteventlisteners-from-chrome-webdriver-python)). Is it a way that I can do this?