# How to send keyboard shortcut SHIFT CONTROL c in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using `selenium` in `python` and I am trying to open developer tools by using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver   
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get('http://nostarch.com')

elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')  
elem.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.CONTROL, 'c')
```

But no matter how much times I try, it doesn't seem to work.
   Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931234/how-to-open-chrome-developer-console-using-selenium-in-python) question here it is very similiar. So, install AutoHK and open notepad and type: `Send ^+J` and save as `script.ahk`. Then, load into your file like this:

```
browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/groups/GNexus5/")
import os
os.system("path_to_script.ahk/script.ahk")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open dev console try:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
elem.click()
browser.switch_to.active_element().send_keys(Keys.F12)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately this didn't work. All the other commands like CTRL A work fine but it doesn't seem to open dev tools

Comment: I get this error when i type browser.switch_to.active_element() i get this error: http://pastebin.com/51URKa0i

Comment: Could you tell me what is the reason you need to open dev tools while `selenium` session?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply i want to open dev tools to make a program where you can select any element on a webpage

Comment: @Vagif.A, I'm quite sure that this is not actually what you need :) You won't be able to handle dev tools with `selenium`... But you still could try to handle web-page with `driver.page_source` + `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: @Andersson - does the reason make a difference to the recommended solution ?