# How to send Keys like Command C in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I think the Title says it all. I am finding a way to send Command C and Command V using selenium in Python. What I want is that it opens a page, presses Command L and then Command C to copy, and then Command V to paste it somewhere else, but I couldn't find it anyway! Can anyone help?

I tried using the ActionChains, driver.sendKeys method but nothing seem to work, so I came here in the hope to search for an answer. Let's see what happens!

Comment: I would have suggested using autohotkey, but you are on mac. There might be an alternative. If you find one, this SO answer might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268860/how-to-send-keyboard-shortcut-shift-control-c-in-selenium

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ActionChains`

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys('C').key_up(Keys. COMMAND).perform()
```

This will send Command+C

Comment: Thanks, Rahul, but this works for Command+A and maybe COMMAND+C too, but not for COMMAND+P or COMMAND+L for example!

Answer (score 0):

import keys frist

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Then use any of :

```
element.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND+"a") 
element.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND,"a")
```

### Both works you don't have to use action class

Comment: Thanks, PDHide, but this doesn't work for COMMAND+L for example!

Comment: did you try (Keys.COMMAND+"l")

Comment: What are you trying to do with command l ?